# Why one torx screw just doesn't turn as the others?

Tags: hard-drive

I want to disassemble a hard drive. On the bottom side, all the screws attaching the circuit turns with my T5 screw driver, except for one, with which the screwdriver spins without moving the screw, even if it seems identical to the others.

On the top side I have the same problem (although I haven'tested all the others screws), and it is with the screw located on the same side at the bottom one.

[image: Bottom]
[image: Top]

Comment: Hard to tell from the pictures, but are the screws stripped?  Take a rubber band and put it over the screw, then insert the T5 driver, and see if you can get it to turn that way.  [Use Rubberband to remove a stripped screw](http://lifehacker.com/5462520/remove-a-stripped-screw-with-a-rubber-band)

Comment: @N.Greene I'm afraid my DIY English is quite bad. What does the screw are striped means? They seem fine to me,I can't spot any difference with the screw's that work. I'll try the rubber band trick.

Answer (score 0):

When you turn either one, does the other one also turn?

If this is the case then maybe they're connected and you're basically turning them both as it could be a link between them.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I think they aren't so aligned they're connected.

Comment: Also, the screw I'm trying to turn doesn't turn either.